# How to rewrite category URL in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, routes

I have the following structure of categories:

default
->myCategory1
-->SubCat11
---->Category111
---->Category112
-->SubCat12
........
->myCategory2
-->SubCat21
---->Some_category

Now my category URL is

```
http://<host_name>/myCategory1/SubCat11/Category11
```

or

```
http://<host_name>/myCategory2/SubCat21/Some_category
```

I want to do category url structure like this:

```
http://<host_name>/SubCat11/Category111
```

or

```
http://<host_name>/SubCat21/Some_category
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: There are two aspects to your question: 1) how to resolve these requests and 2) how to get the system to generate URLs in this manner. Make sure that whatever answer you select addresses both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Because your essentially trying to do this backwards, there is no foreseeable way to do this within Magento.

You might be able to get away with rewriting the URL within your .htaccess file. You would typically create a rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^/SubCat11/Category111/ /Category111/SubCat11 [L,R=301]
```

This does seem rather cumbersome. Perhaps it can be improved with wildcards:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /$2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can i to do custom router for categories? For example, create custom module and rewrite some classes or extend default magento router.